# How to truncate with jQuery

Tags: jquery, truncate

I have a list `<li>Baths 2.00</li>` and i want to remove `.00` to show only the decimal 2

How i can remove the `decimal part` with `jQuery`.

Do you have any solutions?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

you should use `toFixed` :

`123.45.toFixed(0)` //123

And it's not related to jQuery but pure JS.

regarding your html : (assuming the numbers are at last place)

```
$("li").text(function (i,n){  var g=$(this).text().split(' ');
                            g[g.length-1]= parseFloat(g[g.length-1],10).toFixed(0); return g.join(' ');})
```

http://jsbin.com/ifoZOjE/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example mate..Hope this might help u ...:)
IF you have the part that contains the `number` in a `variable` or something use the below

```
 var iNum = 5.123456;
```

The `toPrecision()` method formats a number to a specified length.

```
  iNum.toPrecision();    // Returns 5.123456
  iNum.toPrecision(5);   // Returns 5.1235
  iNum.toPrecision(1);   // Returns 5
```

The `toFixed()` method converts a number into a string, keeping a specified number of decimals.

```
  iNum.toFixed(2);        // Returns "5.12"
```

//Removes the part after the point.Be sure there is not point part that comes in the word part..:)

```
var value = $('li').text();
$('li').text(value.split('.')[0])
```